# Open mapping theorem in complex analysis - an edge case

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic and not constant.

> **Claim:** If $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open, then $f(U)$ is open.

Now by the open mapping theorem, we know that for every connected open set $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ the image $f(D)$ is either open or one single point. So the claim would be proved, if we knew that $f$ cannot be constant on any connected component of $U$. Is that so?

Comment: a holomorphic function is constant iff it is constant on some non-empty open set.

Comment: @IttayWeiss If its domain is connected.

Comment: OP's domain is $\mathbb C$.

Comment: ah, yes, I meant 'entire' instead of 'holomorphic'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is assumed entire, if it were constant on any nonempty open set, it would be constant by the **identity theorem**. As  $f$ is non-constant on every nonempty open set, $f(U)$ is open for every open $U\subset\mathbb{C}$.

Without the assumption of being defined on all of $\mathbb{C}$, one would need to require that $f$ be non-constant on every connected component of its domain.